# Revising my query

Tags: mysql

A question for homework is to show the total amount of houses with multiple presents. The list below shows which ones they are but I cannot work out the query to show them as a total of 6. I am still new and learning Mysql, my apologies for the ignorance.

Mysql data

```
**address**                   **Number of presents per home**
2 Bay Road                              2
2a Neptune Road                         2
45 Bay Road                             2
59 Black Street                         2
65 Mainway Avenue                       3
89 White Street                         2
```

Query used:

```
SELECT address, SUM(goodBehaviour) AS `Number of Houses with Multiple presents`
FROM wishlist
GROUP BY address
HAVING SUM(goodBehaviour) >1;
```

I have tried a few other queries to total the Address column but have not been able to show my desired output. Thanks.

Comment: If the data you showed be accurate, then you should be getting back six addresses, each having 2 presents each.  What are you actually getting, or what is your real data set?

Comment: What Im needing to show is the total amount of addresses in one column to show that there are 6 houses in total that have multiple presents. I dont need to show how many presents they have but just to show the total houses. I just cant figure out how to show just that as a column, i used this query to try work it out,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you sum the `goodBehaviour` field's values, but you should count the number of addresses that have more than 1 presents.

If each address has just 1 record in your table (based on your sample data):

```
select count(address)
from wishlist
where goodBehaviour >1
```

If you can have multiple records for a single address, then in a subquery you need to sum the number of presents and count the number of addresses in the outer query, where the total number of presents are more than 1:

```
select count(address)
from
    (select address, sum(goodBehaviour) as presents
     from wishlist
     group by address) t
where t.presents>1
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand, thats really helpful, Im still getting used to multiple select statements and using multiple aggregates. My apologies I should have advised that there is duplicate addresses as there are more than 1 child receiving presents. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you need total number of houses - you can use your query as subquery:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT address, SUM(goodBehaviour) AS `Number of Houses with Multiple presents`
FROM wishlist
GROUP BY address
HAVING SUM(goodBehaviour) >1) x;
```

Comment: This also worked out how I needed, thank you for your help as well. The x at the end of the query, what does this initiate?

Comment: @S.A the `x` at the end of the query is an alias. You must use an alias for a derived table (derived table=subquery in the from clause). If you check out my answer again, you can see that I used the letter `t`.